# Suppress prompt for save file in emacs with recompile

Tags: emacs

I usually setup a nontrivial compile command, then frequently call `'recompile`. Is there a way to suppress the prompt for saving files similar to the approach in auctex invoked with `(setq TeX-save-query nil)`? I find it very annoying to always have to save manually, or press `y` at the prompt. When I hit recompile, I want all files saved if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
compilation-ask-about-save is a variable defined in `compile.el'.
Its value is t

Documentation:
Non-nil means M-x compile asks which buffers to save before compiling.
Otherwise, it saves all modified buffers without asking.

You can customize this variable.
```

---

Here is the function `recompile`, which demonstrates that it *also* uses the variable `compilation-ask-about-save`:

```lisp
(defun recompile (&optional edit-command)
  "Re-compile the program including the current buffer.
If this is run in a Compilation mode buffer, re-use the arguments from the
original use.  Otherwise, recompile using `compile-command'.
If the optional argument `edit-command' is non-nil, the command can be edited."
  (interactive "P")
  (save-some-buffers (not compilation-ask-about-save)
                     compilation-save-buffers-predicate)
  (let ((default-directory (or compilation-directory default-directory))
    (command (eval compile-command)))
    (when edit-command
      (setq command (compilation-read-command (or (car compilation-arguments)
                          command)))
      (if compilation-arguments (setcar compilation-arguments command)))
    (apply 'compilation-start (or compilation-arguments (list command)))))
```

---

See also the doc-string for `save-some-buffers` -- "*Optional argument (the prefix) non-nil means save all with no questions.*"

```
save-some-buffers is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
`files.el'.

It is bound to C-x s.

(save-some-buffers &optional ARG PRED)

Save some modified file-visiting buffers.  Asks user about each one.
You can answer `y' to save, `n' not to save, `C-r' to look at the
buffer in question with `view-buffer' before deciding or `d' to
view the differences using `diff-buffer-with-file'.

This command first saves any buffers where `buffer-save-without-query' is
non-nil, without asking.

Optional argument (the prefix) non-nil means save all with no questions.
Optional second argument PRED determines which buffers are considered:
If PRED is nil, all the file-visiting buffers are considered.
If PRED is t, then certain non-file buffers will also be considered.
If PRED is a zero-argument function, it indicates for each buffer whether
to consider it or not when called with that buffer current.

See `save-some-buffers-action-alist' if you want to
change the additional actions you can take on files.
```

Comment: For the impatient: I put `(setq compilation-ask-about-save nil)` into my `.emacs` and it works.